# Код для Онлайн витрины на python

Tags: python

Подскажите код для "Онлайн витрины" желательно на python.

Требования:

- принимало XML;
- создание категорий;
- сортировки по фильтрам;
- желательна корзина покупок;

Описание:
Нужен код, который бы принимал от клиентов XML их товаров на сайте или подобное, распарсивал их в БД, совершал сортировки с помощью фильтров по категориям, товарам.

Может кому попадалось подобное. Поделитесь ссылками, хотя бы на что-то похожее, методики, проектирование, или все что может помочь для разработки.

Answer (score 2):

Поигрался запросами, и нашел подобное тому что я ищу.
Если кто-то будет искать, то подобные вещи называются - **Системы eCommerce** на python или django.

Вот список ссылок что накопал:

- [Список решений (EN)](http://flaviusim.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/)
- [Сорсы одного из решений](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar) и [пример запуска с описание (RU)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145786/)
- [еще одно решение](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/)
- [Список решений (RU)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/101471/)

Прочитав их описания, понял, что нужно выбирать тот который максимально подходит под ваши нужды (КЭП). Или по параметрам, например одно из решений работает на django 1.1, что в моём случае не очень удобно.

Вопрос не закрываю, может кто еще поделится подобными решениями.

Comment: openERP тогда, если eCommerce

там как раз, вроде, был встроенный плагин для витрины

Answer (score 1):

не встречал готовых решений (но это не значит, что их нет).

а так смотрите в сторону django (самая простая для начала обучения, плюс есть готовые модули для некоторых задач типа корзины), lxml.

Comment: Я не для обучения, нужно для сайта, набирать клиентов, брать у них XML их товаров, выводить у себя, принимать заказы и отправлять заказы клиентам.
Естественно могу и сам это написать, уже начал проектирование, на python(django). Но хотелось увидеть пример подобной реализации, чтобы допустить как можно меньше ошибок. Но к сожалению ничего не нарыл.